# Validação não redirecionar PHP / JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um formulário de validação, porém ele não está redirecionando para a página após a verificação do acesso quando uso o JQuery, mas quando uso diretamente no PHP, ele funciona.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#login-form').submit(function() {
     data = $('#login-form').serialize();

     $.post("validar.php",{
            d: data,
     },
      function (d) {
        console.log(d);
       if(d == 1){
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
$params = array();
$dados = parse_str($_POST['d'], $dado);
$mensagem = $metodos->validaUsuarios($dado["TipoAcesso"],$dado["LoginAcesso"],$dado["SenhaAcesso"]);
echo $mensagem;
```

**Método PHP**

```
 public function validaUsuarios($tipoAcesso,$loginUsuario,$senhaUsuario){    
....
  $sqlAcessos = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM acesso_usuarios WHERE Matricula = '%s' AND SenhaAcessos = '%s' AND TipoAcessos = '%s'",mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$loginUsuario),mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$codificado),mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$acesso));

if($contarAcessos == 0){
           $erro = 1;
       }else{
   .....
return "<script>window.location.href='sistema/';</script>";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal seria você retornar uma flag em seu método e tratar a lógica de redicionamento no frontend. Retornando ao invés de seu window.location.href, retornar **true** ou **false**. No callback do post, próximo ao `console.log` você verifica a resposta e apenas adiciona  o `window.location.href='sistema/';`

PHP Function:

```
public function validaUsuarios($tipoAcesso,$loginUsuario,$senhaUsuario){    
    $sqlAcessos = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM acesso_usuarios WHERE Matricula = '%s' AND SenhaAcessos = '%s' AND TipoAcessos = '%s'",mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$loginUsuario),mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$codificado),mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$acesso));
    if($contarAcessos == 0){
       return 1;
    }else{
       return 0;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login-form').submit(function() {
        var data = $('#login-form').serialize();
        var post = {
            d: data,
        };
        var callback = function(d) {

            console.log(d);

            if (d == 1) {
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            } else {
                window.location.href = 'sistema/';

            }
        };
        $.post("validar.php", post, callback);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfeito Rafael. Muito obrigado!